# Getting a table to stack properly with other divs

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I've seen some similar questions to this but nothing really comprehensive that actually addresses this specific issue; if there's a good thread about this already that I somehow missed I apologize in advance.

So I have kind of a multi-part issue and my solution for the first part has created the second issue.

I have a 4 column layout in which the contents need to maintain the same height uniformly, something like this:

[image]

The second and 4th boxes here would have a background color and the height needs to stay at the same height as the other two, which will be images. Currently the surest way I can find to make this happen is to mark it up like a table and set the cell height to 100%, like so:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 25%;">
   <figure><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/business" /></figure>
   </td>
   <td class="bg-brand-dark" style="height: 100%; width: 25%;">
   <div class="block-padding-hor">
   <h3 class="text-inverse h6"><strong>Featured Corporate News</strong></h3>

   <hr class="rule-part--bright center-block" />
   <p class="text-inverse h6">Hardly Dude, a new &#39;vette? The kid&#39;s still got, oh, 96 to 97 thousand, depending on the options.</p>

   <p class="text-center"><a class="currentURL" href="">Continue Reading</a></p>
   </div>
   </td>
   <td style="width: 25%;">
   <figure><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/business" /></figure>
   </td>
   <td class="bg-gray-dark" style="height: 100%; width: 25%;">
   <div class="block-padding-hor">
   <h3 class="text-inverse h6"><strong>Featured Corporate News</strong></h3>

   <hr class="rule-part--bright center-block" />
   <p class="text-inverse h6">Hardly Dude, a new &#39;vette? The kid&#39;s still got, oh, 96 to 97 thousand, depending on the options.</p>

   <p class="text-center"><a class="currentURL" href="">Continue Reading</a></p>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

This solved my first problem quite well but created a new one. Any subsequent content that I add below this markup gets "overran" by the table above it, like so ("not desired" is what's currently happening):

[image]

So my question is, is there a good reliable way to mitigate this? I just assumed a table would behave similar to a block element and stack accordingly, but this does not seem to be the case. Thanks in advance for any advice, even if it's a needlessly harsh word accompanied by a link to a preexisting thread that addresses this issue!

::EDIT::

I did not include any of the CSS because it's unlikely any of it is having an impact on this, but if it seems necessary to understand the issue just comment and I'll add it in.

::EDIT 2::

Per requests, adding the CSS here though, like I said, it's mostly just setting background colors and centering things:

```
<style>
  .img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
  }


  .bg-brand-dark {
    background-color: #004892;
  }


  .block-padding-hor {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }


  .rule-part--bright {
    border: 2px solid #08b5fe;
    width: 50%;
  }


  .center-block {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }


  .text-inverse {
    color: #ffffff;
  }


  .h6 {
    font-size: 13px;
  }


  .text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .bg-gray-dark {
    background-color: #4D4F53;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Yes CSS is needed, to understand it better.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to say "Please don't post any CSS! Let us guess!"

Comment: This is all I can see from your question https://jsbin.com/rijomi/edit?html,css,js,output. PS: why would you use <figure> HTML5 element? SEO-wise engines are already good friends with `<img>` tags and the `alt` attribute. Without the `<figcaption>` there's no much use of it... 
Also, inline styles? Use a Stylesheet instead. You are already well using  classes.

Comment: I'll add css, though all it's doing is setting background colors and centering text so, like I said, it's likely having no impact but I'll add it anyway. As far as the figure tag; this is an in progress thing that's gone through different changes, that will be cleaned up but kind of relying on people's ability to overlook erroneous things.

Comment: For the record (mostly in response to Roko): This is something that is going through iterations and is in an in-development state; the inline styles are only in there while I'm still building it and trying different things, I'm aware it's not the way to go. I'm also aware that there might be markup items (figure tag) that may not be necessary; again, that will get cleaned up. Merely looking for insight on the specific issue mentioned, not an invitation to nitpick at items that are likely not affecting it as I'm generally aware of best practices and am only trying things to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Tables have traditionally been the reliable way to create layouts of equal height columns.

However, since the advent of [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), the same behavior can be achieved with minimal code and greater flexibility.

There are several ways to establish equal height columns with flexbox:

1. Use the [`flex-grow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)
   This property specifies what amount of space the item should take up within the flex container. With `flex-grow: 1` (or the `flex: 1` shorthand), the boxes will always occupy all available space in the flex container. This keeps boxes equal height regardless of content size or quantity.
2. Use the [`align-items` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).
   This property controls how flex items distribute available space along the cross axis. The default value is `stretch`, which expands the flex item along all available space. This keeps boxes equal height because each will stretch the height of the container by default.
3. Use the [`min-height` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) on the flex container.

**HTML**

```
<article id="container">
    <section class="box">1</section>
    <section class="box">2</section>
    <section class="box">3</section>
    <section class="box">4</section>
</article>
```

**CSS** (excluding ornamental styles)

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
    overflow: auto;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rv315Ls/5/)

In the demo, what ever amount of content (images included) is put into one box, will result in sibling boxes taking the same height.

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Comment: Thanks for the indepth response, this is great info. We're starting to integrate flexbox into our code more and more, the difficulty with this is that we have to give ie8 considerations, which is totally doable just a little extra work. I figured out my issue though, will be posting an answer below.

Comment: No need to incorporate flexbox.  The OP's approach was good, just had some problematic CSS.  Also, according to [your link regarding flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), IE10 uses a syntax different from the current standard.  Why deal with that headache?

Comment: @divinecomedian, because in his question he asked, *is there a good reliable way to mitigate this?* ..  and there were no answers posted after 40 minutes, and I prefer flexbox for layouts than tables.

Comment: downvoter, i'm open to your feedback.. i don't take any of this personally, so fire away..

Comment: I figured, but didn't want to assume. If you see anything wrong with the code itself lmk. It does exactly what the OP asks, down to the color boxes.

Comment: Anyways, tables are meant for tabular data, not layouts. So it's a "hacky" solution, which probably was a necessary evil some years ago, but its not the case any more. +1 to flex

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after a lot of inspecting in the dev tools, I was able to find the problem. This was not included in my markup as it was not a part of my markup but built into the cms that I was working inside of.

The preceding DIV had a "max-height" setting on it with a pixel value. Because of this, it was pushing the table content into the content below it. So there you have it; a simple solution that was just lying right outside my view.

Comment: Ah, good job.  I didn't think there would be any other reason for that issue to happen.  Some CMS's add some whacky CSS!